# TestNG equivalent of running NUnit tests with a .dll file on NUnit UI

Tags: junit, nunit, testng

So far I have been using eclipse to run testng tests, which requires me to code out a small program that includes a testng project; however this means every time I need to setup someone else's machine I have to pass alone the source codes so that they can run on their own eclipse.

I am sure it is not the best practice as when I was doing it in C#, I can build a .dll file to be imported in nunit's UI and I can execute the test from the nunit's UI. In this case I will just need to feed new users with the .jar or w/e file and tell them to use that UI tool to execute the tests. My questions fall below:

1) Are there any equivalent of nunit UI's for testng?

2) If so, how can I generate a .jar or w/e file of the testng project?

Comment: How does [tag:nunit] relate to your current problem?

Comment: @ClickRick I use nunit to demo that it has a nice UI to run tests on without runnning tests in IDEs; and I don't know if junit has something similar, or it has to be run on IDEs.